# How do I include today in the time axis in Rickshaw

Tags: d3.js, time-series, rickshaw, timeserieschart

I'd look this up in Rickshaw's documentation if it had any.  Does it?

I want my time axis to include the current date, even if there isn't a point there.  I already worked around this by duplicating the last data point, but I'd prefer if that point didn't show up as a point in the hover-highlighter.  Perhaps that's something I can override differently?

Speaking of points, can I get it to draw the points even if I'm using the area renderer?

Comment: If you want today's date to show, you have to include it in the data.

Comment: That is really against the logic that is expected from a visualization library. Programmers should have the ability to affect how the data is displayed, without resorting to changing data just for that purpose...